# Cannot access to a specific block of XML file with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, xelement

I am trying to get a specific block of a XML, I am using function load to take all my XML file and it works fine. When I am debugging i can see all the file. The problem is about when I am trying to get a specific value of xml.

I am using XElement of LINQ library. So, here is an example of my xml file:

```
-<Mission xmlns:z="http:..." xmlns:i="http:..." xmlns="http:..." z:Id="1">
    +<ActiveBullsEye z:Id="2" i:type="BullsEye">
    -<ActiveFlightPlan z:Id="7" i:type="FlightPlan">
        <AIRTAC z:Id="8"/>
        <Active>false</Active>
       -<Aircraft z:Id="9" i:type="a:Tanker" xmlns:a="http:...">
       -<ACColor xmlns:b="http:...">
             <b:A>255</b:A>
             <b:B>169</b:B>
             <b:G>169</b:G>
             <b:R>169</b:R>
             <b:ScA>1</b:ScA>
             <b:ScB>0.396755248</b:ScB>
             <b:ScG>0.396755248</b:ScG>
             <b:ScR>0.396755248</b:ScR>
```

I need to access block (ACColor) and then do a for statement to get all of these values. But I am trying something like this and not function for me:

```
XElement xdocument = XElement.load(filepath) //This works
XElement missionBlock = xdocument.Element("Mission") //(ERROR) This not get Mission tag

foreach( XElement acColor in missionBlock.Elements("ACColor") ) { // (ERROR) Not found ACColor
    ...
}
```

Could you help me to access to all values of ACColor node?

Comment: [Here is some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-queries-linq-to-xml). You will need to use the xml namespace in your query.

Comment: I will check, problably namespace is one of the problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XElement xDocument = XElement.load(filepath);  // This works
var ns = xDocument.GetDefaultNamespace();

      in missionBlock
            .Elements(ns + "ActiveBullsEye")
```

and to get at for instance the value of `z:Id` :

```
var z = xml.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("z");
var id = (string)xElement.Attribute(z + "Id");
```

Do not use var when you create a namespace from a string:

```
var ns1 = "http://something";         // ns1 is a string
XNamespace ns2 = "http://something";  // ns2 is a namespace
```

And you really need a namespace z for `z + "Id"` to work.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works for me. But if you can tell me why is necessary to include namespace in this sentence may help me greatly.

Comment: Because your XML file defines that namespace. It defines `z:`,  `i:` and  a third one without a prefix, that is the default ns.Later on it also defines `a:` and `b:`. Better get up to speed with xml namespaces.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then if i need to take a value of the specific namespace (like z and i) I will need to declare this namespace previously like you did with GetDefault... It could seems like this? var ns = "http:..." If i want to refeer to i.

Comment: Yes, except _not_ using `var`. Write `XNameSpace z = "http:...";` . There is an overloaded conversion define that does not work with `var` on the left.

Comment: Ok. Exists other namespaces like z:Id='410'. In this case how can i declare this namespace?

Comment: No, that is not a namespace, but an attribute `Id` in namespace `z`.  I will edit a little.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xdocument = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\sta01\test.xml");
        var xmlns = "http:...";
        var missionBlock = xdocument.Root;
        foreach (
            var acColor 
            in missionBlock
                .Elements(XName.Get("ActiveBullsEye", xmlns))
                .Elements(XName.Get("ActiveFlightPlan", xmlns))
                .Elements(XName.Get("Aircraft", xmlns))
                .Elements(XName.Get("ACColor", xmlns)))
        {
            var channel = acColor.Element(XName.Get("A", xmlns));
            Console.WriteLine($"A: {channel.Value}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It works with this doc:

```
<Mission xmlns:z="http:..." xmlns:i="http:..." xmlns="http:..." z:Id="1">
    <ActiveBullsEye z:Id="2" i:type="BullsEye">
        <ActiveFlightPlan z:Id="7" i:type="FlightPlan">
            <AIRTAC z:Id="8"/>
            <Active>false</Active>
            <Aircraft z:Id="9" i:type="a:Tanker" xmlns:a="http:...">
                <ACColor xmlns:b="http:...">
                    <b:A>255</b:A>
                    <b:B>169</b:B>
                    <b:G>169</b:G>
                    <b:R>169</b:R>
                    <b:ScA>1</b:ScA>
                    <b:ScB>0.396755248</b:ScB>
                    <b:ScG>0.396755248</b:ScG>
                    <b:ScR>0.396755248</b:ScR>
                </ACColor>
            </Aircraft>
        </ActiveFlightPlan>
    </ActiveBullsEye>
</Mission>
```

Comment: It is necessary to use namespace to get values in a xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary like code below :

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement color = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ACColor").FirstOrDefault();

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = color.Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: This solution seems pro, but I do not know why you used a dictionary to get the values. It could be that in the future you will need to use this values ​​and you could take it from the dictionary instead of realize another search in the xml?

Comment: You could use a List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> since you are getting two values.  I just think if you are going to use a List of pairs you might as well put it in a dictionary.